# Diode lasers tapered amplifiers

Tags: laser

I'm trying to understand how a tapered amplifier works, but I can't find any good resources.  Can anyone point me to any resources where the way they work is explained? Or could anyone here explain it to me?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you read about tapered amplifiers? Any specific questions about what you read?

Comment: There is a brief introduction in [this pdf](http://www.m2k-laser.de/info/m2k%20Produktflyer%20Tapered%20Amplifier%20web.pdf).

Comment: Searching for "Tapered amplifier diode laser" I get a bunch of hits.